# How can I run a local Django site with a separate app folder?

Tags: django, project-structure, django-apps

I'm developing a new Django site. It uses some existing Django apps and I'm building some of my own.

Current folder structure (truncated):

```
projects/
- mysite/
  - .git/
  - conf/
  - mysite/
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
  - myapp/
    - __init__.py
    - admin.py
    - models.py
  - manage.py
```

I'd like to make my site and apps available as separate Git repositories. In other words, someone may want to clone/contribute to the whole site, or they may want to clone/contribute to just an app.

According to the [Packaging your app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/reusable-apps/#packaging-your-app) section of **Advanced tutorial: How to write reusable apps** the following folder structure is required for separate site and app folders:

```
projects/
- mysite/
  - .git/
  - conf/
  - mysite/
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
  - manage.py
- django-myapp
  - .git/
  - myapp/
    - __init__.py
    - admin.py
    - models.py
  - setup.py
```

But in [Using your own package](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/reusable-apps/#using-your-own-package) the same tutorial suggests that the only way to make and use local modifications is to:

1. Modify the app folder
2. Run `python setup.py sdist` to build the app
3. Run `pip install --user /path/to/django-myapp.tar.gz` to install it
4. Run the Django site

How can I organise these folders so that I can easily modify either site or app code, and immediately run the site locally? In other words, avoid building and importing a local tarball each time.

Comment: Simplest way would be to put the app name into your project's `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

My naive reading is that the following (untested) structure should work, with `myapp` excluded from the virtualenv used to run the site locally...

```
projects/
- mysite/
  - .git/
  - conf/
  - mysite/
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
  - myapp/ --> symlink to projects/django-myapp/myapp
  - .gitignore --> ignores myapp/
  - manage.py
- django-myapp
  - .git/
  - myapp/
    - __init__.py
    - admin.py
    - models.py
  - setup.py
```

Obviously releases should be tested and coordinated carefully, so that released versions and published dependencies work together correctly.